# Proof of $AB=BA=O_n$ when $\ A^2+AB+B^2 = 2BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let n be a natural number and $\ A$,$\ B$ two real matrices of dimension 2 and at least one of them is invertible. Then if $\ A^2+AB+B^2 = 2BA$ prove that $AB=BA=O_n$. If I add $BA$ to the LHS then I have $\ (A+B)^2=3AB$ but if at least one is invertible,that is still not enough to prove we can do $\ a^3 + b^3=(\ a + b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$. Any help?

Comment: Your question seems wrong. If $A$ and $B$ are $2\times2$, what does it mean by $BA=0_n$? Is $n=2$? Even if so, the statement is wrong. An easy counterexample is given by $A=I_2$ and $B$ is the $2\times2$ rotation matrix for angle $\pi/3$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample. Take the matrices $A=I_2$ and
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $A^2+AB+B^2=2BA$, because $B^2-B+I_2=0$, but $AB\neq 0$, and $BA\neq 0$.